# Recyclerview scroll to empty Edit Text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am using Edit text as a view of android Recycler view but, when a user does not enter any value in Edit text then I am not able to show an Error message or auto scroll on that empty Edit text. I am storing some data into the database using recycler view edit text, I searched very much but I didn't found any helping material. I want to submit that recycler view data before validating all fields (Edit text).

Comment: Please describe the problem better and show us your code

Comment: Do you want to validate the EditText whenever: 1) User input 2)Click "save" button or something 3)Anything else? And you want to scroll to that EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
int counter = 0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<stockData.length;i++) {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < stockData[i].length; j++) {
                                            if((stockData[i][0]==null || stockData[i][0].matches("")) ||
                                                    ((stockData[i][1]==null || stockData[i][1].matches("")) ||
                                                            (stockData[i][4]==null || stockData[i][4].matches("Stock"))))
                                            {
                                                counter++;
                                                //Log.d(Constants.TAG,"sale is empty and index is "+i);
                                                mPromoter_recyclerView.scrollToPosition(i);
                                                break;
                                            }

                                        }
                                        if(counter>0)
                                            break;
                                    }
```